# Show that f is a local homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that $f: S^1 \to S^1$, $f(z)=z^n$, is a local homeomorphism, that is every point $z_0\in S^1$ admit a neighborhood U such that restriction of $f$ at $U$, $f_U: U\to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism.

I tried to show it using  a property of covering, that is a covering is a local homeomorphism, but I would like to find a proof that not using covering.

Comment: The mapping is $e^{i\theta}\mapsto e^{in\theta}$, so locally it is like $\theta\mapsto n\theta$. Isn't that enough?

Comment: No it isn’t enough

Answer (score 2):

Consider any $z \in S^1$. Choose $\theta \in \mathbb R$ so that $e^{i\theta}=z$. Consider also the open subset $U \subset S^1$ defined by 
$$U = \{e^{i t} \mid \theta - \frac{\pi}{2n} < t < \theta + \frac{\pi}{2n}\}
$$
We have
\begin{align*}
f(U) &= \{e^{itn} \mid \theta - \frac{\pi}{2n} < t < \theta + \frac{\pi}{2n}\} \\
     &= \{e^{is} \mid \theta n - \frac{\pi}{2} < s < \theta n + \frac{\pi}{2}\}
\end{align*}
Notice furthermore that the restricted map $f : U \to f(U)$ is continuous and injective, because the interval $\theta n - \frac{\pi}{2} < s < \theta n + \frac{\pi}{2}$ is an open interval of length $\pi$. The inverse of $f : U \to f(U)$ is a continuous map, given by the formula
$$f^{-1}(e^{is}) = e^{i s / n}, \quad \theta n - \frac{\pi}{2} < s < \theta n + \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
So the restricted map $f : U \to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism. We've therefore found an open subset around every point of $S^1$ on which the restriction of $f$ is a homemorphism, therefore $f$ is a local homemorphism.

Comment: And surjectivity of f?

Comment: Surjectivity of $f : U \to f(U)$ is made completely explicit by the formula for $f^{-1} : f(U) \to U$, although I did have an error in the domain for that formula, which I will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Take $U$ to be $\frac{1}{2n}$th of the circle (we may rotate the circle so $U$ contains $z_0$), so more precisely
$$
U = \left\{ e^{\theta \pi i} \in S^1 : 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{1}{n} \right\}.
$$
Then $U$ maps to the upper half of $S^1$ under $f$. Clearly $f$ is injective, and of course it is surjective onto its image. So $f$ is a bijection $U \to f(U)$.

Now $U$ is a closed set in a compact space, so $U$ is compact. Furthermore, $S^1$ is Hausdorff. So we have a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, and so it must be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Why U is closed?? U is neighborhood then it’s open by definition of neighborhood

Comment: And why f is continuous?

Comment: For me a neighbourhood of $z_0$ is usually any set $U$ such that there is an open set $V$ with $z_0 \in V \subseteq U$. Even if you want an open set, you can use my argument to show that $f: U \to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism and then restrict to $V = U - \{0, e^{\pi i / n}\}$ (which is just removing the endpoints).

Also, $f$ is continuous as a function $S^1 \to S^1$, restricting it to a subspace of $S^1$ preserves continuity.

Comment: Okay but why U is closed?

Comment: Can you explain me?

Comment: It's the complement of the open set $\{e^{\theta \pi i} \in S^1 : \frac{1}{n} < \theta < 2 \pi\}$>